# What is DFS in Elasticsearch "DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH"?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is **DFS** in Elasticsearch *"DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH"*?

what is the abbreviations of **DFS**?

Comment: perhaps depth-first search?

Comment: have you used elasticsearch?

Comment: No, but DFS is a common abbreviation for depth-first search in the computer algorithms context.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The DFS stands for "Distributed Frequency Search".
Excerpt from the elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html) :

> The second workaround is to add ?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch to
>   your search requests. The dfs stands for Distributed Frequency Search,
>   and it tells Elasticsearch to first retrieve the local IDF from each
>   shard in order to calculate the global IDF across the whole index.
>
> Tip Don’t use dfs_query_then_fetch in production. It really isn’t
>   required. Just having enough data will ensure that your term
>   frequencies are well distributed. There is no reason to add this extra
>   DFS step to every query that you r